# Turn off cookie prompts in Lynx

Tags: configuration, lynx

How can I turn off cookie prompts and disallow cookies in the Lynx browser?

Here is my `.lynxrc:`

```
ACCEPT_ALL_COOKIES:FALSE
SET_COOKIES:FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

That's the wrong syntax for `.lynxrc` (it's correct for `lynx.cfg`—the two files use different format).

The documentation for the features in `lynx.cfg` is extracted from its comments into the website:

- [`ACCEPT_ALL_COOKIES`](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/body.html#ACCEPT_ALL_COOKIES) (website):

  **`ACCEPT_ALL_COOKIES`** – Cookies
  Description

  If **`ACCEPT_ALL_COOKIES`** is set TRUE, Lynx will accept cookies from all domains with no user interaction. This is equivalent to automatically replying to all cookie 'Allow?' prompts with "A"lways. Note that it does not preempt validity checking, which has to be controlled separately (see below). The default is defined in userdefs.h and can be overridden here, or in the .lynxrc file via an o(ptions) screen setting. It may also be toggled via the -accept_all_cookies command line switch.
  Default value

  ACCEPT_ALL_COOKIES:FALSE
- versus [`lynx.cfg`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/lynx-snapshots/blob/f1f158e96efc530b81c7247f1081b0fc2801a0a9/lynx.cfg#L1352)

  ```
  .h2 ACCEPT_ALL_COOKIES
  # If ACCEPT_ALL_COOKIES is set TRUE, Lynx will accept cookies from all
  # domains with no user interaction.  This is equivalent to automatically
  # replying to all cookie 'Allow?' prompts with 'A'lways.  Note that it
  # does not preempt validity checking, which has to be controlled separately
  # (see below).
  # The default is defined in userdefs.h and can be overridden here, or
  # in the .lynxrc file via an o(ptions) screen setting.  It may also be
  # toggled via the -accept_all_cookies command line switch.
  #
  #ACCEPT_ALL_COOKIES:FALSE
  ```

Because `.lynxrc` is written by the program, there is no need to manually edit it.  Initially (through the 1990s) Lynx settings were either in `lynx.cfg` ***or*** `.lynxrc`, with no overlap.  That was intentional, since Lynx was often used in a kiosk configuration where the user was prevented from changing settings that were intended to be the same for all users.  Later, other developers added features that they intended to be in both the system- and user-configurable files.  Still later (in [2001](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/CHANGES.html#v2.8.4dev.21)), the [**`ENABLE_LYNXRC`**](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/body.html#ENABLE_LYNXRC) feature was introduced to allow users to save any setting.  However, the cookie configuration dates from that interim period, as you can see by the customized comment in the `.lynxrc` file which Lynx would save from the Options menu:

```
# accept_all_cookies allows the user to tell Lynx to automatically
# accept all cookies if desired.  The default is "FALSE" which will
# prompt for each cookie.  Set accept_all_cookies to "TRUE" to accept
# all cookies.
accept_all_cookies=off
```

Comment: Perhaps it's just my reading comprehension skills, but you have two bullet points that you want to contrast ("a versus b") but they both appear to demonstrate the same syntax. Did you mean to mvoe the "accept_all_cookies=off" block into the second "versus" block?  (Both "a versus b" talk about lynx.cfg)

Comment: No, I was pointing out where the documentation for `ACCEPT_ALL_COOKIES` comes from, and in quoting it, the reader might notice the mention of the options-menu.  Following the bullets, I pointed out how `.lynxrc` differs from `lynx.cfg` (there's more than two points in the answer).

Comment: I followed your advice and used the Options menu and turned off cookies and saved to disk which created a .lynxrc file in my home directory. However after restarting lynx. I am still prompted for each cookie. I am trying to prevent the prompt from showing up and want to decline all cookies. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: offhand - depending on the version of Lynx, the cookies might not pass its check for valid cookies and cause the prompt.  The [mailing list](https://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/lynx-dev) is better suited for digging into that

Comment: oh i see, so what i ended up doing is creating an alias for lynx and have it call this: lynx -accept_all_cookies -cookie_file=/dev/null that way the cookies are all accepted by default but sent to /dev/null so they never get written to disk. i am running Lynx Version 2.9.0dev.5 (27 Feb 2020) libwww-FM 2.14, SSL-MM 1.4.1, GNUTLS 3.6.13, ncurses 6.2.20200212(wide)

Answer (score 2):

SET_COOKIES:FALSE does the trick on Lynx Version 2.9.0dev.5 (27 Feb 2020).

If you wish to use your own lynx.cfg, and you are on bash, you need to update .profile and add the following line. You can also execute it directly on the command prompt.

```
LYNX_CFG=~/lynx.cfg; export LYNX_CFG
```

Then ~/lynx.cfg, will look like

```
#includes the default lynx config (Debian distro)
INCLUDE:/etc/lynx/lynx.cfg

SET_COOKIES:FALSE
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks likes lynx's documentation is completely outdated.

`~/.lynxrc` must contain:

```
accept_all_cookies=off
```

Here's how I've found it out. Please delete `~/.lynxrc`, run lynx, press O, and then configure it (don't forget to mark the checkbox: Save options to disk).

---

The utility and its documentation are completely messed up: I've read the sources and `accept_all_cookies` only accepts `TRUE` and `FALSE` both of which are not what the OP is looking for.

There's also the `cookie_reject_domains` option but it doesn't accept wildcards:

```
# Note that in order to match cookies, domains have to be spelled out exactly
# in the form in which they would appear on the Cookie Jar page (case is
# insignificant).  They are not wildcards.  Domains that apply to more than
# one host have a leading '.', but have to match *the cookie's* domain
# exactly.
```

In short, you may want to fix the utility and send them a patch.

Comment: i was using stackoverflow.com to test the cookie behavior and after using this method, i was still prompted for the cookie. which version of lynx are you using?

Comment: Lynx is broken, even its latest development snapshot `lynx2.8.9rel.1.tar.bz2`. There's no way to make it not accept cookies for all sites without a prompt.