# lynx - change Line Edit Style / lineedit_mode

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, lynx

##### What I want to know:

What is the name of the variable name in `/etc/lynx/lynx.cfg` with the option `Line Edit Style`?

I am trying to set it to `Bash-like Bindings`, but I can't find any documentation on that.

---

##### What I have tried:

I know I can set the `Line Edit Style` via the `options menu` by pressing <kbd>o</kbd>. And the [documentation](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/keystrokes/bashlike_edit_help.html) mentions an option called `lineedit_mode`, but couldn't find anything further on that.

Why is `lynx` so poorly documented? :(

Comment: bindings ? Do you mean key bindings ? (Directives starting with KEYMAP:) ?

Comment: This answers your question: [Lynx browser no cookie prompt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600365/lynx-browser-no-cookie-prompt) -- user confusion between `.lynxrc` and `lynx.cfg`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey sorry but could you help me a little further?^^ Okay so those are 2 different files with different formats. But where the hell do I get the `.lynxrc` file from? It says that it "is written by the program", but how? I don't even have a `.lynxrc` :( And what is the equivalent of `lineedit_mode` in `lynx.cfg`? I am so confused^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.lynxrc` is normally written by Lynx to your home directory when you save from the options menu.  It is about 375 lines (too long to quote here), but begins

```
# Lynx User Defaults File
#
# This file contains options saved from the Lynx Options Screen (normally
# with the 'o' key).  To save options with that screen, you must select the
# checkbox:
#       Save options to disk
#
# You must then save the settings using the link on the line above the
# checkbox:
#       Accept Changes
#
# You may also use the command-line option "-forms_options", which displays
# the simpler Options Menu instead.  Save options with that using the '>' key.
#
# There is normally no need to edit this file manually, since the defaults
# here can be controlled from the Options Screen, and the next time options
# are saved from the Options Screen this file will be completely rewritten.
# You have been warned...
#
# If you are looking for the general configuration file - it is normally
# called "lynx.cfg".  It has different content and a different format.
# It is not this file.
```

The `lineedit_mode` section looks like this:

```
# lineedit_mode specifies the key binding used for inputting strings in   
# prompts and forms.  If lineedit_mode is set to "Default Binding" then
# the following control characters are used for moving and deleting:
# 
#              Prev  Next       Enter = Accept input
#    Move char: <-    ->        ^G    = Cancel input
#    Move word: ^P    ^N        ^U    = Erase line
#  Delete char: ^H    ^R        ^A    = Beginning of line
#  Delete word: ^B    ^F        ^E    = End of line
# 
# Current lineedit modes are:
#    Default Binding
#    Alternate Bindings
#    Bash-like Bindings
lineedit_mode=Default Binding
```

and you could edit the file directly, to pre-set any of the settings.   Lynx will read the file if it exists, and use those settings.  But any comments that you might add/modify will be overwritten the next time you save options to disk in the options menu.

The above is the normal behavior, but

- If you happen to be using some other language than English, and if Lynx is configured to support that, then the comments will be in that language (see [this](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/d78ea209be32bcbcebcb91bb2037a9c59af61c9b/charproc.c#L12536)).  But the settings and their values are unchanged.
- Some settings in the options menu (because they either come from `lynx.cfg`, or some developers chose to make them not persistent) are not written to `.lynxrc`, but that can be altered with the [`ENABLE_LYNXRC`](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/body.html#ENABLE_LYNXRC) setting in `lynx.cfg`.

> The forms-based ***O***'ptions menu shows a (!) marker beside items which are not saved to **`~/.lynxrc`** -- the reason for disabling some of these items is that they are likely to cause confusion if they are read from the .lynxrc file for each session. However, they can be enabled or disabled using the **`ENABLE_LYNXRC`** settings.

Answer (score 0):

The full documentation for lynx.cfg is made available in a typical linux kernel documentation form. [here is for v 2.8.3](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx2.8.3/breakout/lynx.cfg)
(2.8.9 current stable todate)

In particular, as far as key bindings are concerned :

```
KEYMAP:<KEYSTROKE>:<LYNX FUNCTION>
```

As fully described from line #2190 as part of here-above linked document.

Comment: So if I want to have the `Bash-like Bindings`, I would have to manually add them all with the `KEYMAP` keyword? Is there no other way? ^^

Comment: @Pixelbog : Yes. But many defaults are already set. This is the only fully documented way I am aware of anyway.

Comment: Do you use `lynx` yourself? And if yes, would you mind to share your `lynx.cfg` file? :)

Comment: I've been using it ages ago and had not changed anything from default. BTW, if @ThomasDickey who commented in OP is actually Thomas Dickey… then… he is the lead dev of Lynx… and therefore… much much more knowledgeable than I can be.

Comment: Wait no way, that is so cool :D I have been reading his name in some posts but couldn't believe that this is the original Thomas Dickey :DD Feels like meeting a celebrity^^